# How can I find in Visual Studio 2022 the setting whether my Blazor Server Side app shall run in 32-bit or 64-bit process?

Tags: blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, 32bit-64bit, target-platform

Sorry for this very basic question. For example in a console app there is a setting like Platform target (Any CPU) and a checkbox like "Prefer 32-bit".
In my Blazor server side app I couldn't see a setting like this. I have just the platform target set to "Any CPU" but cannot see anything related the 32-64- bit processing.

I am asking this question because:

I am using a 3. party nuget package that is working fine on a console app but not on my Blazor server side app. The owner of the package asked me for supporting whether my app is set to 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: If the Solution Platform is set to "Any CPU" then the dotnet runtime gets to choose whether to run as 64 or 32 bit application. On a 64 bit plattform it will run the app as a 64 bit process. If you pick x86 in the solution platform combo box then your app will run as a 32 bit process.